# ¿Cómo validar el ingreso de datos a la db MySQL Java?

Tags: java, mysql

¿Cómo valido que el campo *dni* del cliente no esté ya registrado en la bd?

```
public boolean insertar(Cliente cliente) {

    try {
        CallableStatement callProc = cn.prepareCall("{call SP_Registrar_cliente(?,?,?,?,?)}");

        callProc.setString(1, cliente.getNombre());
        callProc.setString(2, cliente.getDni());
        callProc.setString(3, cliente.getDireccion());
        callProc.setString(4, cliente.getEmail());
        callProc.setString(5, cliente.getTelefono());
        callProc.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Advertencia", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icono);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Botón guardar:

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    cliente.setNombre(txtNombre_Razon.getText());
    cliente.setDni(txtDni.getText());
    cliente.setDireccion(txtDireccion.getText());
    cliente.setEmail(txtEmail.getText());
    cliente.setTelefono(txtTelefono.getText());

    if (accion.equals("guardar")) {

        if (func.insertar(cliente)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro éxitoso", "Mensaje del Sistema",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, checked);
            mostrar("");
            inhabilitar();
        }

    } else if (accion.equals("editar")) {
        cliente.setIdCliente(Integer.parseInt(txtidCliente.getText()));

        if (func.editar(cliente)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Edicion éxitosa", "Mensaje del Sistema",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, checked);
            mostrar("");
            inhabilitar();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Otra manera, como comenta @LuiggiMendozaJ, es utilizar [unique keys](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/exceptions/MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html), **evitando**:

- Acceso previo a la base de datos para chequear existencia.
- Condiciones de carrera, problemas de concurrencia en ambientes multithread al realizar una consulta previa para determinar existencia.

**¿Que són las claves únicas?**

Las claves únicas, como dice su nombre, son un conjunto de atributos que definen la restricción de que **no pueden existir dos tuplas que tengan los mismos valores para esos atributos.**

**¿Como utilizar esta restricción desde Java?**

Si definimos `dni` como unique key e insertamos un `Cliente` cuya `dni` ya se encuentra registrada en la tabla, obtendremos [MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/exceptions/MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html)

Una `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` puede deberse a **varios motivos** (pk violada, fk violada, etc), por lo tanto es necesario **discriminar** cual fue la restricción de integridad que fué violada. En este caso nos interesa saber cuando se violó una `unique key` solamente

**¿Cómo discriminar una violación de clave única de otra restricción de integridad?**

Esa información se obtiene chequeando el `errorCode` de la excepción SQL a traves del método [SQLException#getErrorCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode())

Los `error codes` son **dependientes del motor de base de datos**, por ejemplo, para violación de `unique key` en Oracle es `1`, mientras que en MySQL es `1062`

[MySQL - Error codes table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html)

**Posible implementación**:

```
    public static final int UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATED = 1062;

    public boolean insertar(Cliente cliente) {
        try {
            CallableStatement callProc = cn.prepareCall("{call SP_Registrar_cliente(?,?,?,?,?)}");
            callProc.setString(1, cliente.getNombre());
            callProc.setString(2, cliente.getDni());
            callProc.setString(3, cliente.getDireccion());
            callProc.setString(4, cliente.getEmail());
            callProc.setString(5, cliente.getTelefono());
            callProc.execute();
        } catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
                String msg = "Advertencia";
                if (UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATED == e.getErrorCode ()) {
                    // manejar la excepcion de la manera que corresponda segun la logica de negocio, posiblemente agregando un mensaje de error; tambien se
                    // podria levantar la excepcion a una capa superior mediante "throw e";
                    msg = "El registro ya se encuentra en la base de datos";
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, msg, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icono);
                return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Advertencia", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icono);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

En las situaciones donde los datos a insertar no se encontraban registrados la restriccion de unique key no sera violada y el registro se insertará sin necesidad de realizar una consulta previa.

Comment: Interesante, para un futuro proyecto que haré DM en JavaFX. ¿Lo has probado y funciona? Aunque para mi gusto lo haría en forma de método independiente que sirviese para validar cualquier inserción a la BD.

Comment: Efectivamente. En mi caso lo he utilizado como parte de un método genérico que persiste cualquier objeto. La logica en este caso era catchear violaciones de uniques keys para seguir reintentando inserciones, ya que intervenian dos aplicaciones sobre dos JVM diferentes (sobre la misma tabla). En tu implementación podrías cambiar String strValor por Object objValor y utilizar preparedStatement.setObject(), de manera que puedas chequear por valores de cualquier data type

Comment: Perfecto. He colocado una nota al final de mi respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tener un método para verificar la existencia de cualquier dato. Lo puedes llamar no sólo para una tabla o valor específico, sino para cualquiera, pasándole otros parámetros.

Se puede perfeccionar, por ejemplo, hacerlo que sepa distinguir el tipo de parámetro para pasarlo al preparedStatement. En el ejemplo sólo acepta cadenas.

Por ejemplo:

```
 /**
   * Método para verificar si un registro existe
   * @param conn Conexión a la bd
   * @param strTable Nombre de la tabla
   * @param strCampo Nombre del campo que se usará como criterio
   * @param strValor Valor a buscar
  */

  public static boolean isRecord(Connection conn, String strTable, String strCampo, String strValor) throws SQLException 
  {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Boolean isData=false;

        try 
        {
            String strSQL="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + strTable + " WHERE " + strCampo + "=?";
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL);
            //Esto se puede mejorar, aquí sólo acepta valores del tipo String
            preparedStatement.setString(1, strValor);
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) 
            {
                isData=true;
            }
        }
        finally 
        {
            //No cierro la conexión porque supongo querrás seguir usándola
            rs.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        return isData;
  }
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
if (!isRecord(conn, "clientes", "dni", "1234798-Y")){

    //No existe, insertar   

}
```

---

> **Nota**: Como ha dicho @LuigiMendozaJ en comentarios, este método haría el trabajo en el caso de una aplicación que no manejase
>   conexiones y usuarios concurrentes a la bd (es decir, una aplicación
>   monousuario). Si existe la posiblidad de que varias personas usen la
>   aplicación al mismo tiempo, la solución óptima sería aquella que
>   delega el control de registros duplicados al manejador de base de
>   datos. La respuesta de @MarcosMartinez explica cómo hacerlo.

Comment: O, mejor aún, delegar esta tarea a la base de datos mediante una llave única (`UNIQUE KEY`), que es más eficiente en caso que múltiples aplicaciones accedan a la misma bd/tabla.

Comment: Sería interesante que mostraras una respuesta sobre cómo se manejaría desde Java, @LuiggiMendozaJ

Comment: Lo has dicho, sería interesante. Pero no cuento con el tiempo ahora. Será en otra oportunidad.

Comment: @A. Cedano Esta solución no es thread safe cierto? Podria suceder que isRecord retorne false y al querer insertar posteriormente otro hilo haya insertado un registro.

Comment: Es correcto @MarcosMartínez, esta solución está pensada para una aplicación de escritorio simple, que no maneja conexiones concurrentes a la bd. Sería interesante una solución como la que propone Mendoza.